# send data encrypted from client side to server side to descrypt

Tags: java, encryption, server, client, aes

I want to send from a client to a server data encrypt in order to decrypt in the server side. I encrypt in the client side "123456" in order to decrypt it in the server side by symmetric key.

My code is the following one.

Client code:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InterruptedException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    int port=56321;
    byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] { 127,0,0,1 };
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
    System.out.println(address);
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    byte[] plainBytes = "123456".getBytes();
    byte[] keySymme = {
            0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79
    };//"thisIsASecretKey";
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keySymme, "AES");
   System.out.println("key"+secretKey);

    // Create Cipher instance and initialize it to encrytion mode
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");  // Transformation of the algorithm
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] EncryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);

    DatagramPacket packet1=new DatagramPacket(EncryptedData, EncryptedData.length, address, port);//bytes    

    System.out.println("Sending...");
    socket.send(packet1);
    System.out.println("Sent...");
    socket.close();
}
```

Server code:

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    int port=56321;
    int port2;
    byte[] keySymme = {
            0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79
    };//"thisIsASecretKey";
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keySymme, "AES");
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    byte[] data = null;

    while(true){
        data = new byte[1024];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        socket.receive(packet);            
        port2=packet.getPort();
        InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();            
        String message=new String(packet.getData());
        System.out.println("Address "+address+" Port "+port2+" Message "+message);
        System.out.println("Listening...");

        byte[] EncryptedData=packet.getData();

        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // Reinitialize the Cipher to decryption mode
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey, cipher.getParameters());
            byte[] plainBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(EncryptedData);
            System.out.println("Decrypted data "+plainBytesDecrypted);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

}
```

The encrypt part in the client side is ok but when the server is going to decrypt the data from the client this error appears:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at Server.main(Server.java:48)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of this matters. You should be using TLS, which is far more secure than a single layer of fixed key symmetric encryption.

Comment: I agreee but the goal is not to send encrypted data as a communication between the cleint and the server, the goal is about the authentication from the client to the server, so I though that the best way would be this one.

Comment: It's not.  There are a large number of things wrong with the code you have on a security level...  In fact you could MITM a connection and login as someone else very easily.